# Selenium (Java) Select tag selection error

Tags: selenium

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn-excel-select-prd btn btn-sm btn-base">엑셀다운로드</button>
    <select id="selectLength" cdgrp="PAGE_LEN" class="form-control input-sm" style="">
        <option value="10" title="10개씩 보기">10개씩 보기</option>
        <option value="20" title="20개씩 보기">20개씩 보기</option>
        <option value="50" title="50개씩 보기" selected="">50개씩 보기</option>
        <option value="100" title="100개씩 보기">100개씩 보기</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woxEc.png)

I want to choose the 4th option.
However, if I write the code as below, an error "element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated" appears. How can I solve it?

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("selectLength"));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByIndex(3);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCCAo.png)

Comment: It's possible that "selectElement" is not visible yet.  You'll want to use a webdriverwait with expected condition of elementToBeClickable.

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3L)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#selectLength > option:nth-child(4)"))).click();                            I added the this code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Use it here: WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("selectLength"));  The above tries to click on an option from a Select pulldown that hasn't been opened yet.  The "Select" type would I think do that for you... (i.e. select.selectByIndex would probably click the pulldown to open first...)